# Mixing libraries with and without RTTI with GCC on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, rtti

I've been banging my head on an issue and before I continue injuring myself some more, I'd like to confirm:

Is it possible to have a GCC project that uses libraries that are compiled with and without RTTI?

So, for example, I have project A (compiled without RTTI) that uses library B (compiled with RTTI) and library C (compiled without RTTI). In theory, is all that supposed to compile and link with no problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the binaries were built with (or without) the `-fno-rtti` switch? If so, I can't see any reason why this should not work - RTTI is only provided for classes with virtual functions in any case, so there is no major change in binary format or anything like that. Are you experiencing any specific problems?